# Redirection URLs with Its Values and Post Data at Spring

Tags: java, spring, redirect, resttemplate

I have an application that has a REST interface. Also I have another application that is Spring based. Instead of sending requests into first application I want to send data and parameters into my Spring application and then post it to the original one.

I have tried resttemplate but Media type is custom and data is binary. I get some errors. What is the proper way for it?

**EDIT:**

Here is what I've tried:

```
 @POST
 @Path("/nao")
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public String update(@PathParam("lemma") String lemma, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
 StringBuilder baseURL = new StringBuilder("http://localhost:8080/daro/comiko/nao?");

 MultivaluedMap<String, String> requestParams = uriInfo.getQueryParameters(true);
 Object data = ((WebApplicationContext) uriInfo).getContainerRequest().getHeaderValue("-d");
 paramMap.put(param, APIUtils.paramListToString(requestParams.get(param)));
 baseURL.append(param).append("={").append(param).append("}&");

 String url = baseURL.toString();
 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "custombin"));
 HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>((String) data, headers);

 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
 return String.valueOf(restTemplate.postForLocation(url, entity, paramMap));
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the errors you got using the RestTemplate? Also it would help if you displayed the Rest Endpoint and the code you used to post it it

Comment: Ok good! What kind of errors are you getting?